# tkinter - bind keypress event to label

Tags: python, events, tkinter

If I wanted to bind a keypress event to a Label to change its text, my first reaction was to bind a buttonpress to the label, which colours the label blue, and binds a keypress to the label.
At it's most basic, it would look like this:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

def prep(event):
    event.widget.config(bg='light blue')
    event.widget.bind('<Key>', edit)

def edit(event):
    print(event.char)

example = Label(frame, text='Click me')
example.pack()
example.bind('<Button-1>', prep)
mainloop()
```

To my surprise, the buttonpress event worked fine, colouring the label, but the keypresses afterwards did nothing.
Replacing event.widget's `bind` with `bind_all` would technically solve this, but obviously this is impractical.
Thanks guys

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The label does not receive the keypress events because it does not have keyboard focus (a label does not acquire keyboard focus when clicked) so you need to give it the focus with the `focus_set` method:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

def prep(event):
    event.widget.config(bg='light blue')
    event.widget.focus_set()  # give keyboard focus to the label
    event.widget.bind('<Key>', edit)

def edit(event):
    print(event.char)

example = Label(frame, text='Click me')
example.pack()
example.bind('<Button-1>', prep)
mainloop()
```

Comment: That is a useful method to know. I struggled to find it on the net, for some reason. Thank you